# How Do I Complete a commerce order checkout Programatically?

Tags: commerce

I want to Complete a commerce order checkout Programmatically after the transaction has been completed  so far I, have done this creating a commerce order programmatically and saving it. Now, I want to complete the checkout process programmatically I am calling `commerce_checkout_complete($order_id);` but it sets the page in exit mode.

Comment: I'm not a commerce guy, I admit, but I'm curious what " sets the page in exit mode" is supposed to mean. Something comemrce-related? If so, OK, I don't know, I don't need. But if it's something general, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have created a product programatically .Then i have added it to the cart , Then redirected it to a custom form for transaction purpuse, payment is being made in xml format after getting a reponse from payment gateway  as ACCEPTED i have to set the order state to complete.